# Keeping div open after hovering an element

Tags: jquery, css

I have some trouble with jquery / css. When hovering over a link, I want to show a box, but this box mustn't disappear while moving the cursor from the link to the box. At the moment this works but another thing is, that the box also should be closed if you move the cursor from the link to any other part of the site which is not the box.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5TLC/4/) demonstrates this behaviour. Just move the cursor from the link to some other place on the site (but avoid hovering the appearing box) and you will see, that the box is still there.

This is what my jQuery code looks like:

```
$("#link").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#cart_box").fadeIn();
});
$("#cart_box").mouseleave(function() { 
    $("#cart_box").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include your `cart_box` inside the `a`,

```
<div id="left"> 
    <a href="#" id="link">
        <div style="margin-left: 31px;">
            <div class="cart_img">IMG</div>
            <span style="margin-left: 10px;">My Cart</span> 
        </div>
        <div id="cart_box">

    </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

then change your functions like this

```
$("#link").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#cart_box").fadeIn();
});
$("#link").mouseleave(function() { 
    $("#cart_box").fadeOut();
});
```

but keep in mind, by default `a` will be a `inline` element, so when the box is visible and you try to hover into the box, it might flicker, as you are moving out of `a` for 1px maybe and then moving in, to avoid that you need to add some height to `a`, equal to the gap between the `cart_box` top and the `IMG` bottom , for that you would need your `a` to be `block`, add this css to your `a`

```
#left a{
    display:block;
    height:50px; //anything to cover the 1px or 2px between cart_box top and the IMG bottom
}
```

also,see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a5TLC/7/

P.S: you may want to change the `width` of your `cart_box`, once you have it inside the link.

Comment: Add another empty div between your menu element cart_img that extends to your cart_box and make sure that's in the anchor tag too if you want to prevent it from fading out and back in if you move your cursor from the cart_img to cart_box

Answer (score 0):

Just encapsulate the link and the box on a div, and apply the mouseleave to that div.

This happens because the mouseleave event cannot be called if the mouse doesn't enter the box.

Comment: Already tried that, but it doesn't work. Apparently after leaving the link it also leaves the new box around everything although link and box are in it. See the updated fiddle in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You **do not need javascript** for this. You should simply include your 'box' inside the `a` and display it on hover of the link. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<a>
    hover me
    <div>to see me</div>
</a>
```

CSS (unprefixed!):

```
a div {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
}
a:hover div {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I added a transition / transform to illustrate that these simple things can easily be done with pure css, and are often a lot smoother and faster.

See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/6gT2u/